# Is there a way to re-enter a Facebook conversation you left?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I have left some conversations on Facebook and I was wondering if there is anyway you can rejoin it *without* someone else that is still in it re-adding you -- that or is there a way you can access the chat history again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have the message link you should be able to access the history up to the point you left the group. There is no way to re-join without someone adding you back via native/API or otherwise.